# FFMPEG not exporting audio OR exports audio with still video

Tags: ffmpeg

Trying to utilize ffmpeg to convert a mp4 to DNxHD, then wrap it in an MXF.  The ultimate goal is to get this into Avid Media Composer.  I've been having issues with this particular command, where no audio is ever exported:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 24 -i Test_fix.mp4 -vcodec dnxhd -vsync drop -b:v 36M -s 1920x1080 -threads 2 -vf colormatrix=bt601:bt709 -c:a aac -f rawvideo BLAH.mov
```

If I tweak the above command by removing the force of the "rawvideo" option I get audio, however the video then sits on the first frame and never advances:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 24 -i Test_fix.mp4 -vcodec dnxhd -vsync drop -b:v 36M -s 1920x1080 -threads 2 -vf colormatrix=bt601:bt709 -c:a aac -r 24 BLAH.mov
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?  Here is the output from running the second time:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 24 -i Test_fix.mp4 -vcodec dnxhd -vsync drop -b:v 36M -s 1920x1080 -threads 2 -vf colormatrix=bt601:bt709 -c:a aac -r 24 BLAH.mov
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Test_fix.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2021-07-01T17:19:54.000000Z
  Duration: 00:01:05.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6336 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 6016 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-01T17:19:54.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-01T17:19:54.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> dnxhd (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mov, to 'BLAH.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: dnxhd (DNXHD) (AVdn / 0x6E645641), yuv422p(tv, bt709/unknown/unknown, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 36000 kb/s, 24 fps, 12288 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-01T17:19:54.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 dnxhd
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-01T17:19:54.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 aac
[mov @ 0x7fd129013000] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[mov @ 0x7fd129013000] Encoder did not produce proper pts, making some up.
frame= 1577 fps=133 q=1.0 Lsize=  290993kB time=00:01:05.70 bitrate=36279.7kbits/s speed=5.54x
video:290168kB audio:809kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.005816%
[aac @ 0x7fd129019000] Qavg: 22541.643
```

Comment: Copy and paste all text from the log from command #2.

Comment: @llogan posted output logs, would appreciate any help!

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v dnxhd -b:v 36M -r 24 -vf "scale=1920:1080,colormatrix=bt601:bt709" output.mxf` and if it fails provide a link to `Test_fix.mp4` so we can try to duplicate the issue.

Comment: @llogan Thanks but the MXF portion is being taken care of outside FFMPEG.  I just need to get it into playable audio/video as DNxHD.  Problem is it is not coming out as a valid DNxHD.

Comment: *"Thanks but the MXF portion is being taken care of outside FFMPEG"* If the final format is MXF what reason do you output MOV? Why not keep it within MXF even if you're going to remux using something else? *"Problem is it is not coming out as a valid DNxHD."* Is something telling you that it is invalid? I thought the problem was, "the video then sits on the first frame and never advances". What player does it not advance in? Does it play OK with ffplay/mpv/vlc?

Comment: @llogan I am bringing this into an AVID.  I am utilizing raw2bmx to handle the MXF portion of that, as I haven't had any luck with AVID's specific requirements of wrapping to an MXF in ffmpeg.  I am also now realizing, that ffmpeg is needing to output a rawvideo dnx for this to be successful, hence why I stuck with that originally.

Comment: if I could simplify this..  even just issuing this command produced no audio:

ffmpeg -i Test_Scout_fix.mp4 -vcodec dnxhd -b:v 36M -s 1920x1080 -r 24 -f rawvideo ABC.dnx

Why?  What am I not understanding?  Is it because the rawvideo is simply just that.  If so, how can I pipe the audio together with?

Comment: Raw video is not DNxHD. Raw video has no audio. It is only raw video. If you want DNxHD use `-c:v dnxhd` and output to MXF or MOV with an appropriate audio format such as PCM.